# Show all applications using keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications

**Problem:**

Show all installed applications in the /Applications folder using keyboard shortcut.

**Desired solution:**

Potential utility/tool that runs in the background to show all applications upon keyboard shotcut. I know there has been a software that does this but do not remember the name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See [Get a complete list of all applications installed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98826/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-all-applications-installed) to understand why this is not as simple as it sounds (well, the keyboard shortcut is, but only if the base question is answered).

Comment: OS X has an app that does this called [Launchpad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5548). Do you want something more?

Comment: Finally found the application after hours of searching. It's called [Bevy](http://www.bergdesign.com/bevy/) and is available at the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, the shortcut is built-in to OSX:

- Switch to Finder (clicking on the desktop is quick)
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

This brings up the Applications folder in the Finder. (Or were you asking for something else?)