# Find date of upgrade from Mojave to Catalina

Tags: mojave, software-update, catalina

I always update my 2017 Macbook pro as soon as an OS update comes out. I guess I learned my lesson of not installing the .0 version of any Mac OS update. I finally gave up on fixing various issues with Catalina and got a new loaner from my employer with Mojave on it. Now trying to copy data over to Mojave.

Is it possible to find the date when I upgraded my Macbook pro from Mojave to Catalina? I need to find the time machine backup that was from Mojave so I can restore from that TM backup. Maybe, there is a file somewhere in the filesystem which contains the name of the release?

Comment: In Terminal: `softwareupdate --history | grep Catalina`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a complete list of all applications installed?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98826/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-all-applications-installed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the most direct route to get *software update* information is using **Terminal** and the `softwareupdate` *command*, e.g.:

```
softwareupdate --history
```

To filter for **macOS Catalina**, use e.g.:

```
softwareupdate --history | grep Catalina
```

As shown in the output from my system:

```
$ softwareupdate --history | grep Catalina  
macOS Catalina                                     10.15      10/08/2019, 07:24:17  
$
```

You can also use `softwareupdate -h` to output the internal help. or use `man softwareupdate` for its manual page.

Answer (score 5):

These are the steps to follow:

1. Go to applications
2. Click utilities
3. Go to System Information
4. On the left scroll down to software
5. Click system installations and sort by software name
6. Look for the update and when it was installed, an example as follows:

[image]